# Insert into table using select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, loops, stored-procedures

I have a select query which returns n records . I want those to insert into the same table with the Different B_ID's my B_ID's will be (4,51,16,7) how i can write easy query. I can do that by for loop . But i want some simpler and optimized query
Hide   Copy Code

```
INsert into S_FACT(S_ID,B_ID,G_ID,AMOUNT)
  (select '150',B_ID,G_ID,AMOUNT from S_FACT where S_ID=2 and  B_ID =(2))
```

My list will be like this (4,7,22,55)

```
    INsert into S_FACT(S_ID,B_ID,G_ID,AMOUNT)
      (select '150','4',G_ID,AMOUNT from S_FACT where S_ID=2 and  B_ID =(2))  
      INsert into S_FACT(S_ID,B_ID,G_ID,AMOUNT)
      (select '150','7',G_ID,AMOUNT from S_FACT where S_ID=2 and  B_ID =(2))          
    INsert into S_FACT(S_ID,B_ID,G_ID,AMOUNT)
      (select '150',22',G_ID,AMOUNT from S_FACT where S_ID=2 and  B_ID =(2))
  INsert into S_FACT(S_ID,B_ID,G_ID,AMOUNT)
      (select '150',55',G_ID,AMOUNT from S_FACT where S_ID=2 and  B_ID =(2))
```

etc depending on the list

Comment: Your query looks okay . . . although you should remove the paraentheses around the `select` statement.  They are unnecessary.

Comment: how do you determine which record gets which `b_id`? or are you looking to duplicate *all* records returned with *all* the possible `b_id`s you listed?

Comment: I have List of B_ID(4,7,9,22) i want to loop over the list of B_ID and insert into the table

Comment: Updated the Question With more details

Answer (score 0):

> I have a select query which returns n records

You should ***supply*** your select in the question text then.

you could:

```
insert into S_FACT( S_ID, B_ID, G_ID, AMOUNT)
select '150', sq.b_id, s.G_ID, s.AMOUNT 
from S_FACT s
cross join (
    -- Substitute here Whatever your select query is, selecting only the b_id
    select 4 as b_id
    union all select 51
    union all select 16
    union all select 7
) sq
where s.S_ID=2 and s.B_ID = 2
```

Comment: As i said my list won't be constant it will be of size n(where n>0) and are not hard coded which will come dynamically

Comment: you said you have a `select query` which will have `n` records.  you then specified a list of `b_ids`, not a select query.   Please try to be more specific.  You can still use my solution, just insert the records into a temporary table and cross join onto it.